# Obtain git hook event information

Tags: git, githooks

In a git hook, environment variables are set to provide the event information that fired the hook. Accessing environment variables for the correct commit information worked fine except when downgraded to git 1.7.1 which do not supply all of the git environment variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to upgrade git from 1.7.1. This may seem like a simple oversight and that is correct. It appears 1.7.1 added functionality in the same way as 1.7. The second and third place numerical positions apparently did not have a distinct meaning. For my situation upgrading to 1.7.6 fixed the issue.

I hope this information is helpful to others writing git-hooks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware that there can be hooks in all git repositories. So you can have hooks both in your local git repository and the remote repository.

In the case of the `post-commit` hook we are normally talking about a local repository where you want something executed when you do a local commit. It is unclear how a race condition would occur here.

1) Each commit has the hash of the previous commit embedded. So the order of commits is always well defined. Several commits cannot compete for position.

2) Yes. See http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks. Different hooks receive different information. The `post-commit` has not got any parameters, though.

3) The hooks are really executing in your local machine, so you can use the environment variables on your local machine.

4) You have to write the code in the hook. There are samples in the `.git/hooks` directory.

Comment: Klas, Thank you for the response. I am focused on obtaining the correct commit in a post-commit hook when two commits have been executed at nearly the same time. Normally, a local repository would be used by only one developer but that is the not the case for this question. -Ben (I need to change my alias)